# Inspect object attribute pickling sizes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

My object pickle dump is unexpectedly huge. I'd like to investigate which attribute causes that. How do I do that?

I've tried both `sys.getsizeof` and `pympler.asizeof`, they didn't give me the answer.

This question is more of the general approach, but if you really want to know, my object is a sklearn trained logicstic regression model. My pickle dump is 500MB, but none of the individual attributes from `dir(model)` reflects it:

```
import sys
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
for a in dir(clf):
    print('%25s\t%10d\t%10d' %(a, sys.getsizeof(getattr(clf, a)), asizeof(getattr(clf, a))))

                    C           28          32
            __class__         1464           0
          __delattr__           56          56
             __dict__          648        8944
              __dir__           72           0
              __doc__         8359        8360
               __eq__           56          56
           __format__           72           0
               __ge__           56          56
     __getattribute__           56          56
         __getstate__           64           0
               __gt__           56          56
             __hash__           56          56
             __init__           64           0
    __init_subclass__           72           0
               __le__           56          56
               __lt__           56          56
           __module__           78          80
               __ne__           56          56
              __new__           72           0
           __reduce__           72           0
        __reduce_ex__           72           0
             __repr__           64           0
          __setattr__           56          56
         __setstate__           64           0
           __sizeof__           72           0
              __str__           56          56
     __subclasshook__           72           0
          __weakref__           16          16
      _estimator_type           59          64
     _get_param_names           64           0
    _predict_proba_lr           64           0
         class_weight           16          16
             classes_         6536        6536
                coef_          112         112
    decision_function           64           0
              densify           64           0
                 dual           24          24
                  fit           64           0
        fit_intercept           28          32
           get_params           64           0
           intercept_           96          96
    intercept_scaling           28          32
             max_iter           28          32
          multi_class           52          56
              n_iter_          100         104
               n_jobs           28          32
              penalty           51          56
              predict           64           0
    predict_log_proba           64           0
        predict_proba           64           0
         random_state           16          16
                score           64           0
           set_params           64           0
               solver           58          64
             sparsify           64           0
                  tol           24          24
              verbose           24          24
           warm_start           24          24
```

My training data is around the 500MB scale, so I guess it was captured unnecessarily somewhere and I want to remove that when saving to file. Note that it's not that obvious because I do have some preprocessing sklearn pipeline before feeding the result into the classifier (not part of the pipe)

**Update 2:**

Some code, simplified from my actual company code:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty="l2", C=100)
clf.fit(X, target)
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clf, f)
```

Let me know what other information you think might be helpful.

Comment: Please provide more details, if possible.

Comment: Added some details. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using `dir`, you should use `vars`, i.e. `my_object.__dict__`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out and it give a sublist of the above, the numbers are still the same, which doesn't explain the big pickle output..

Comment: Right, so when I said give more details, I meant about *what exactly* you are doing when pickling, and what exactly you are doing when creating your `clf`...

Comment: Added some more. Also, I tried dumping out each attribute separately and I now narrowed it down to `coef_`. So now that makes sense, since my vocabulary is around 50000 words, having 800 targets (I know it's nonsense, this is just a dummy model). So I now know what to do. But still, my original question is how do I investigate this in a more efficient way in Python, as I was expecting those `*sizeof` methods will tell me instantly which attribute is the largest.

Comment: Firstly, don't look in `dir` look in `vars`, but `coef_` should be an array, what does `coef_.nbytes`. I don't know how `pympler` works, but anyway, `sys.getsizeof` only returns the size of the *object*, not the size of the attributes themselves. So you have to use a recursive strategy, generally. This becomes more complicated with `numpy` objects, since they are C-extensions.

Comment: So `pympler` implements this recursive strategy, but it is mainly useful for pure python user-defined classes and standard-lib objects. Here's an [issue](https://github.com/pympler/pympler/issues/36) where pympler is reported to work incorrectly with `numpy` objects. Maybe see if you have the latest versions of `pympler`/`numpy` installed? Here's a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787327/pympler-asizeof-vs-sys-getsizeof