# Split a Python List into Chunks with Maximum Memory Size

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a python `list` of `bytes` values:

```
# actual str values un-important
[
    b'foo',
    b'bar',
    b'baz',
    ...
]
```

**How can the list be broken into chunks where each chunk has the maximum memory size below a certain ceiling?**

For example: if the ceiling were 7 bytes, then the original list would be broken up into a list of lists

```
[
    [b'foo', b'bar'], # sublist 0
    [b'baz'], # sublist 1
    ...
]
```

And each sublist would be at most 7 bytes, based on accumulated length of the list's contents.

Note: each sub-list should be maximally packed, in the order of the original list.  In the example above the first 2 str values were grouped because it is the maximum possible under the 7 byte limit.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: It's a fairly complex/expensive operation to get the size of a an object in Python since you need to recursively iterate over container types as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/548562. It's an interesting question though, why do you want to split the list into chunks based on size?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to achieve. The size of the dicts themselves will be consistent since they don't actually contain the value, just a reference to the value. Is this an XY problem? On my system, `sys.getsizeof` returns `240` for all of these: `{'a': []}`,
    `{'b': [1]}`,
   `{'c': [1, 2] * 999}`

Comment: Could single dictionary be above this 1 KB threshold?

Comment: @IainShelvington these dictionaries are eventually being broadcast to AWS Kinesis which has a max batch record size of 5MB.

Comment: @DeepSpace, that is a good point.  I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil how are you passing the data to Kinesis? Will you have to serialize the dictionaries before sending them? If so then it may be easier to query the size of the serialized objects

Comment: Note that recursive ``sys.getsizeof`` is generally incorrect. For example, the size for ``[1, 1, 1, 1, ...]`` would be wrong because the element ``1`` is re-used/interned, consuming memory only once.

Comment: Are you certain you need the size of the Python objects holding the data instead of, say, the size of a serialisation (JSON, BSON, ...) of the data?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `sys.getsizeof([1, 1]) == sys.getsizeof([1, 2])`

Comment: @DeepSpace A) That's not recursive ``sys.getsizeof``, but only the size of the list (header + pointer array). B) ``2`` is also interned. C) ``sys.getsizeof([1, 2**64]) == sys.getsizeof([1, 2**64])`` but ``sys.getsizeof(2) != sys.getsizeof(2**64)``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok I got what you meant, pretty much the same as what I meant in my first comment

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated my question accordingly.  The dictionary + sub-value debate was not the main thrust of my question.  Rather, I'm more interested in the maximum packing & chunking aspect.

Comment: @DeepSpace I have updated my question accordingly.  The dictionary + sub-value debate was not the main thrust of my question.  Rather, I'm more interested in the maximum packing & chunking aspect.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Are you looking for a faster solution or what? What should happen if a single item in your input list is larger than the threshold? BTW the correct term of binary `str` is `bytes`, when I first read the question it got me confused.

Comment: @norok2 Yes, something more "pythonic" or faster than a simple for loop.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil I would say that a simple for loop is as "pythonic" as you can get with this.... [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) #3 "Simple is better than complex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is with `functools.reduce`.

```
l = [b'abc', b'def', b'ghi', b'jklm', b'nopqrstuv', b'wx', b'yz']

reduce(lambda a, b, size=7: a[-1].append(b) or a if a and sum(len(x) for x in a[-1]) + len(b) <= size else a.append([b]) or a, l, [])
```

`a` is an empty `list` and `b` is an item from the original `list`.

`if a and sum(len(x) for x in a[-1]) + len(b) <= size`
check if `a` is not empty and sum of length of `bytes` in the last appended `list` and length of `b` is not exceeding `size`.

`a[-1].append(b) or a`
append `b` to the last appended `list` of `a` and return `a` if the condition is `True`.

`a.append([b]) or a`
make a `list` with `b` and append the new `list` to `a` and return `a`

Output;

```
[[b'abc', b'def'], [b'ghi', b'jklm'], [b'nopqrstuv'], [b'wx', b'yz']]
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem of optimal splitting of a sequence such that the elements satisfy a given max/min condition while keeping the order of the elements can be solved greedily.
Hence, you need to iterate over the input sequence only once and maintain a buffer of elements.
In Python this can be elegantly coded with a generator, which will have the advantage of not needing to create the result.

The bulk of the algorithm for your problem is as follows:

```
def split_by_size(items, max_size, get_size=len):
    buffer = []
    buffer_size = 0
    for item in items:
        item_size = get_size(item)
        if buffer_size + item_size <= max_size:
            buffer.append(item)
            buffer_size += item_size
        else:
            yield buffer
            buffer = [item]
            buffer_size = item_size
    if buffer_size > 0:
        yield buffer
```

where the last parameter delegates the issue of determining the size of a given item to the specified callable.
I will not dwell upon this, but I will assume that a simple `len()` will do.
Also, this assumes that each element, individually would satisfy the condition, otherwise one should handle also this case.

Testing the above code:

```
import random


k = 10
n = 15
max_size = 10

random.seed(0)
items = [b'x' * random.randint(1, 2 * k // 3) for _ in range(n)]
print(items)
# [b'xxxx', b'xxxx', b'x', b'xxx', b'xxxxx', b'xxxx', b'xxxx', b'xxx', b'xxxx', b'xxx', b'xxxxx', b'xx', b'xxxxx', b'xx', b'xxx']

print(list(split_by_size(items, k)))
# [[b'xxxx', b'xxxx', b'x'], [b'xxx', b'xxxxx'], [b'xxxx', b'xxxx'], [b'xxx', b'xxxx', b'xxx'], [b'xxxxx', b'xx'], [b'xxxxx', b'xx', b'xxx']]
```

---

Also, if you are willing to store the result of the split in a `list` anyway, the code for the above approach can be made slightly more compact:

```
def chunks_by_size(items, max_size, get_size=len):
    result = []
    size = max_size + 1
    for item in items:
        item_size = get_size(item)
        size += item_size
        if size > max_size:
            result.append([])
            size = item_size
        result[-1].append(item)
    return result
```

but also slightly slower (see benchmarks below).

---

You could also think of using `functools.reduce()` (basically the same as [@NizamMohamed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091966/5218354)), and the code will be shorter but perhaps also less readable:

```
def chunks_by_size_reduce(items, size, get_size=len):
    return functools.reduce(
        lambda a, b, size=size:
            a[-1].append(b) or a
            if a and sum(get_size(x) for x in a[-1]) + get_size(b) <= size
            else a.append([b]) or a, items, [])
```

and certainly less efficient as `get_size()` is being called for every element of the "candidate" inner list for every element considered, which makes this `O(n k!)`, `k` being the average number of elements in each sub-sequence. For some timings, see benchmarks below.

---

I would not be surprised to a solution using `itertools.accumulate()`, but that would also bound to be quite slow.

---

The simplest approach to speed things up would be to use [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).
Here, this was applied to `split_by_size()`.
For both of them the code would be unchanged.

Benchmarking all this we obtain (`_cy` stands for the Cython-compiled version while `_nb` stands for the Numba-compiled version):

```
%timeit list(split_by_size(items * 100000, k + 1))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 281 ms per loop
%timeit list(split_by_size_cy(items * 100000, k + 1))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 181 ms per loop
%timeit list(split_by_size_nb(items * 100000, k + 1))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.17 ms per loop
%timeit chunks_by_size(items * 100000, k + 1)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 318 ms per loop
%timeit chunks_by_size_reduce(items * 100000, k + 1)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop
```

Note that while the Numba-compiled version is much faster than the alternatives, it is also the most brittle since it requires the `forceobj` flag set to `True`, and this may lead to unstable execution.

Anyway, I hardly believe this would be a bottleneck if the final goal is to send the grouped items through some I/O operation.

---

Note that the algorithm is pretty much the same as other answers, I just find the code here a bit cleaner.

Comment: this works well! for anyone looking for potential other sizing callables based on memory I tested out asizeof module from pympler as well as sys.getsizeof as stand ins for len in the example. more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787327/pympler-asizeof-vs-sys-getsizeof

Answer (score 1):

The simple, naïve approach would be:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

# init input data - as per the comments, data type does matter, 
# for memory calculation, and for the sake of example -
# string is probably the easiest case:

lts=list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

data=[{letter: "".join(np.random.choice(lts, np.random.randint(100, 700)))} for letter in lts]

# parameters setup:

threshold=1024
buffer=[]
buffer_len=0
res_data=[]

for el in data:
    len_=sys.getsizeof(list(el.values())[0]) # I assumed it's one key, one value per dictionary (looks like this from your question) 
    if(buffer_len+len_>threshold):
        res_data.append(buffer)
        buffer=[el]
        buffer_len=len_
    else:
        buffer.append(el)
        buffer_len+=len_

if(buffer_len>0):
    res_data.append(buffer)

print(res_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it short and sweet:

```py
l = [b'foo', b'bar', b'baz']

thresh = 7
out = []
cur_size = 0
for x in l:
    if len(x) > thresh:
        raise ValueError("str too big")
    if cur_size + len(x) > thresh:
        cur_size = 0
    if cur_size == 0:
        out.append([])
    out[-1].append(x)
    cur_size += len(x)

print(out)
```

This will output:

```
[[b'foo', b'bar'], [b'baz']]
```

That should be what you want if I understood correctly. Its very simple; All it does is append the strings from the list and checks the combined size of everything in the current list it is appending to-- if the size plus the next item will be greater than the threshold, it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import getsizeof
import math
def chunkify_list(L, max_size_kb):
    chunk_size_elements = int(math.ceil(len(L)/int(math.ceil(getsizeof(L)/(1024*max_size_kb)))))
    return [L[x: x+chunk_size_elements] for x in range(0, len(L), chunk_size_elements)]
```

I wrote this code and it works for me.
It requires access to math