# Setting cachetools LRUCache with maximum size

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

Trying to set [cachetools cache class](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cachetools.Cache)
- more specifically the `LRUCache` inheriting from it.
I want to set `maxsize` based on bytes - which means I need to set `getsizeof` parameter with some `lambda` function for calculation of object's size of in bytes.

Looking into [sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), we can see it's not suitable as I'm about to save in cache custom class with referenced\handles to other objects which will be the critic mass.

Any ideas how can I calculate real bytes in memory for python custom object and what it contains, meaning calculating also referenced size (not pointer size but its content)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the [pympler package](https://pypi.org/project/Pympler/), they've implemented the function you want already.

```
python -m pip install pympler
```

```
from pympler import asizeof
from cachetools import LRUCache

@LRUCache(MAX_BYTES, getsizeof=asizeof.asizeof)
def foo():
    pass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40832098/965778 - according to this I've not convinced this the right package for me, and in example didn't see any proof of concept.
Thanks anyway

Comment: What happens when you try to use it? The documentation says that it is the byte size. The stackoverflow question you linked is about size in memory vs size of the pickled object.

Comment: Seems good to me! What I'm worried about is not the accuracy but the performance of pympler -- I'm writing an ML application which could have many-gigabyte collections. I've implemented disk-based backup caching, but now want to tune in memory cache as well. Is pympler a good idea for very large objects?

Comment: **UPDATE** for numpy arrays, at least, works well! (Very sublinear time in array size) I guess large the issue would only be complex python objects.