# numpy float64, float32, and float16 scalars all use the same number of bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy floats with different precisions, but no matter what precision I am using, 64, 32, or 16, the object is using the same number of bytes (48 for a single float number)! Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
w = np.float32(2)
print(f"{asizeof(w)=}")
w = np.float64(2)
print(f"{asizeof(w)=}")
w = np.float16(2)
print(f"{asizeof(w)=}")
```

Any idea about why it is like this?

Update:

I am using pympler to check the exact size of the object (w) here, but I have also tested this with a huge number of single numpy float numbers each stored as a dictionary value (with different keys), and I can see by eyeballing the RAM usage by the process that no matter what precision I use, the RAM usage does not change.

Comment: Are you really using a huge number of seperate floats in your code, or are you using numpy arrays? Make sure you're doing a relevant comparison for your use case.

Comment: Seems to be a pympler issue much like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787327/pympler-asizeof-vs-sys-getsizeof

Comment: What is `w`? and why exactly do you think it should magically change size every time you assign to it? And how does printing literals assert anything at all?

Comment: @user207421: w is the object returned by np.floatx. Every time I am using a different x (16, 32, 64) so the returned object should be different. I don't see any magic being needed here. What do you mean by printing literals? I am printing what is returned by the pympler asizeof function.

Comment: Why should it be different? How was `w` declared? Why should the size of the same variable keep changing? Please explain. As for your prints, all I can see is literals, and function calls inside literals. If they should be executed I would like to know why.

Comment: You measure the size of the [buffer protocol object](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/05/introduction-to-the-python-buffer-protocol), not the allocated data memory.

Comment: @user207421: first w=np.float32(2), then w=np.float64(2). Clearly, these are two different functions. Functions are called and the returned values are printed. You can test and see that a number is returned by the function and that number is printed on the screen (https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)

Comment: They are two different functions whose result is being stored into the same object. Why should that object magically change its own size? Please explain.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @Diamond - Better than the referenced blog article? Sorry, but no.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: No problem ;-) but thanks for the reference.

Comment: @user207421 this is Python; assignment doesn't store anything "into an object". Variables are references and are not declared. Assignment changes which object is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `pympler` does or how accurate it is in measuring size of `numpy` objects.  `sys.getsizeof` is a more common tool.  I suspect `pympler` tries to get around known limitations of `getsizeof` for lists and dicts, but for `numpy` it's fairly good.

```
In [44]: import sys
In [45]: sys.getsizeof(np.float32(2))
Out[45]: 28
In [46]: sys.getsizeof(np.float64(2))
Out[46]: 32
In [47]: sys.getsizeof(np.float16(2))
Out[47]: 26
```

Those numbers indicate that these objects have a 24 byte 'overhead', with 2 bytes for the 16's data, two more for 32, and 8 for the 64.

Normally we don't work create `np.float64` objects directly.  Rather we make an array with a particular dtype, and get something like a `np.float64` object when we index a particular element.  Keep in mind that `numpy` does not store values by reference (unless it's object dtype, which is more `list` like).

Look instead at an array:

```
In [48]: x = np.arange(24)
In [49]: x.dtype
Out[49]: dtype('int64')
In [50]: x.nbytes
Out[50]: 192           # 24 * 8
In [51]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[51]: 304
In [52]: 304-192
Out[52]: 112           # array 'overhead'
In [53]: y = np.array([0])
In [54]: y.nbytes
Out[54]: 8
In [55]: sys.getsizeof(y)
Out[55]: 120            # same 112 byte overhead
```

So an array has a size of 112 bytes plus its `nbytes`, which we get from `dtype` and `shape`.  That's assuming the array 'owns' its data, that is, it isn't a `view` of some other array.

```
In [57]: type(x)
Out[57]: numpy.ndarray
In [58]: type(x[0])
Out[58]: numpy.int64
```

An "extracted" element of `x` is of type `int64`. The data for `x` is
stored as 24*8 bytes, not as 24 32bytes objects.